# checking existence of file start from name "sample" using php

Tags: php

Could someone help me with how I can check the existance of files which starts with any name like `sample1.pdf`, `sample12.pdf` in a particular folder using PHP? Below is my code for checking a single file.

```
<html>
<?php
if(file_exists("properties/".$owner."/".$property."/sample1.pdf") )
?>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The PHP function glob ([here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.glob.php)) will provide you an array of files that match. So you can do the following:

```
$files = glob("properties/{$owner}/{$property}/sample*.pdf");
```

This will then return an array of files within the "properties/{$owner}/{$property}/" directory that start with "sample" and have an extension of .pdf

You can then loop through the files and do what you need

```
//Check if there are any files and there were not any FATAL errors
if (count($files) > 0 && $files !== FALSE) {
    foreach ($files as $file) {
        //Do something here
    }
} else {
    //There were no matching files
}
```

Hope this helps

Comment: It is just an array or filenames so yes, take a look at the examples on PHP.net with the link I posted :)

Comment: okk thats nice way....but if there are no file present then it will give fetal error in php.....so what can i do??

Comment: Check to make sure that the array contains files, I will update my answer

Comment: If you take a look at that link it says "Returns an array containing the matched files/directories, an empty array if no file matched or FALSE on error." So you just make sure the array has files and does not equal FALSE :) check my updated answer

Comment: no now if there is not single file present then it will display "Array"